# How can I find a longstanding circular reference in an open Excel workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

Using Office365 under WIN11, some old Excel spreadsheets give the "circular reference in an open workbook" message, on opening.

The circular reference, if it really exists, can't be traced via "the last formula entered" as I've been using these files for years.

I can ignore the message, but it would be more satisfying to track and correct/remove it from one or more of the files.

Advice appreciated.

Comment: does this help: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/excel-unable-to-find-cell-circular-reference-error/m-p/2706702

Comment: The link does contain some hints that should be helpful, but I'm not sure they all work in Office365. I've checked every sheet in all three files (two .xlsb and one .xlsx) using Formulas/Error Checking/Circular References, but in all cases the Circular References option is greyed out.. Also, I wanted to go to File/Options to get the error checking to ignore #DIV/0! but it just took me back to the last open sheet (which is my reason for questioning whether the hints work in the Office 365 version of Excel).

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123 Is this article helpful?

Comment: Thank you Lee. From a quick scan I've tried some of the methods in that link already, but will check the rest more carefully as time allows.